# How to use the most basic JavaScript tools to build a slideshow

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to write a JavaScript script that stays as close as possible to basic JavaScript concepts.  I know I could do what I want in jQuery with pretty small and simple code.  I'll eventually use jQuery but for right now I want to avoid it.  I'm trying to animate a basic slideshow:  The first div should be visible at first, then the next shows after one second, then the next, and so on.  I also know that I will eventually need to do something like setInterval instead of the setTimeout that I've used.  But I'll cross that bridge when I get there.

The problem I'm having right now is that I cannot seem to easily access and amend the CSS styles of objects in the DOM.  Perhaps this is something that's just too complicated to stick to basic JavaScript for, and if that's the case, then I might amend this by creating a class which only hides or shows elements, and then include that class in the various elements based on whether I want them hidden or shown.  But if there is a way to access and edit CSS from within base JavaScript I'd like to learn how.

Here's what I've tried so far:

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Slideshow</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="slideshow.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="slide1">
        <p>.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="slide2">
        <p>..</p>
      </div>
      <div class="slide3">
        <p>...</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script src="slideshow.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
div.slide1 {
  visibility: visible;
}
div.slide2 {
  visibility: hidden;
}
div.slide3 {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
var s1 = document.getElementsByClassName('slide1')[0];
var s2 = document.getElementsByClassName('slide2')[0];
var s3 = document.getElementsByClassName('slide3')[0];
s1 = getComputedStyle(s1);
s2 = getComputedStyle(s2);
s3 = getComputedStyle(s3);

console.log(s1);
console.log(s1.visibility);

setTimeout(function() {
  if (s1.visibility === "visible") {
    s1.visibility = "hidden";
    s2.visibility = "visible";
  }
}, 1000);
```

The console complains about line 13 of the JavaScript:

```
NoModificationAllowedError: Modifications are not allowed for this document
```

Can anyone suggest a way around this error, or a different approach to using JavaScript to edit the CSS styles?

Note: The following does not answer my question because it uses jQuery.  [How to make a slideshow in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15394675/how-to-make-a-slideshow-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are extracting the computed CSS style from an element and then store it in the very same variable that you had previously stored the element in.
In order to modify a setting, you are required to write the change back to the element in question, which doesn't happen since you are working on the style info instead of the respective element that produced the style. You would need a construct resembling `<element>.style.<styleproperty>`.

Comment: So in a previous attempt at this I had `var s1 = document.getElementsByClass('slide1')[0].style.visibility`.  However, this results in `s1 == 'visible'` returning `false`.  When I print `s1` it looks like it's just the whole div element and not merely its visibility value.

Comment: Er, that might not be what it was really doing, but it still didn't work, and the console printed the error `Ignoring get or set of property that has [LenientThis] because the “`

Comment: I was rather talking about `<element>.style.visibility = <value>` to actually change the visibility setting.